# Can I have multiple UIAlertViews for one IBAction in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, uialertview, ibaction

Is it possible to program multiple UIAlertViews for one IBAction in Xcode to show at random.  For example: I am making an app with multiple questions shown at random, when the submit button is pressed, an alert is shown saying if the answer is correct or not.  I want there to be different messages for the alert such as one time it shows one message, then the next time it shows a different message at random.  How would I program this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your .h:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController { 
    NSArray *messages;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *messages;
```

In your .m

```
@implementation MyViewController
@synthesize messages;

- (dealloc) {
    [messages release];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    messages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Funny Message", @"Even Funnier Message", @"Hilarious message", @"ROFL", @"OK this is getting boring...", nil];
}
```

When you need an alert:

```
NSUInteger messageCount = [messages count];
int randomMessageIndex = arc4random() % messageCount;

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:[messages objectAtIndex:randomMessageIndex] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

Comment: It says that messages is an undeclared identifier... What do I need to do to fix that?

Comment: When I run the code, the program works for one question, but it then crashes and shows the error "Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"" What am I doing wrong? I have copy and pasted your code so I know that it's all typed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

define the following macro for the project:

for the msg section as try a Array with random Index

```
#define KAlert(TITLE,MSG) [[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:(TITLE) 
          message:(MSG) 
         delegate:nil 
cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease] show]
```

Which could be used as simple call:

```
KAlert(@"Title", @"Message"); 

or KAlert(@"Title",@"[youarray objectatindex:randindex]");
```